# Partitioning on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows-8

I have a laptop. In said laptop I have windows 8.1 and 4 partitions.

My partitions list are as follows:

1. System Partition - Size:350 MB - simple driver
2. Driver C (My windows 8.1) - Size:150 GB - simple driver
3. Driver D - Size:390 GB - simple driver
4. Driver E - Size:390 GB - simple driver

When I install Ubuntu on my laptop, my partitions are:

1. Unknown - Size: 1 MB because I install Ubuntu with my flash.
2. Unknown - Size: 350 MB
3. sda1 - Size: 150 GB
4. sda2 - Size: about 800 GB

I want install Ubuntu on driver E or D but I can not see my drive E or D and drive D and E are sda2.

Comment: You did automatic partitioning during the Ubuntu setup?

Comment: I do not use automatic setup. I use flash to install,too.

Comment: And you want us to do the matching between both partition lists you gave?

Comment: No, I want install Ubuntu on my system on driver E, But I can not see my driver E.

Comment: Take a look at your partitions with gparted  (boot with the live CD - http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php ) and look how this partitions are formatted.

Comment: Where exactly is Ubuntu showing you these Unknown partitions? Is this before the installation, or after the installation? Can you please take a screenshot? If you can't, just take a photo with your mobile phone. Upload your photo to http://imgur.com and give us the direct link.

Comment: Sorry not to directly answer your question as per the rules, but your question _does_ need some clarifications. Where did you get those partitions list from ?
Is Ubuntu already up and running, or do you run it from a _live_ flash drive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ubuntu, partitions are not named with alphabets like in windows. From what you have revealed, it seems that you rather have a single perhaps 1TB drive, that was split up into multiple partitions. This single drive shows up in ubuntu as /dev/sda, where /dev/sda1 will be the first partition, /dev/sda2 will be the second partition and so on...

It is risky to propose a new partitioning scheme without risking your data and existing windows installation, so I would advise you find someone (your local Linux user group perhaps?) or a friend who is a bit more familiar with this to assist you.

Otherwise, generally, the Live CD/USB Stick with automatic partitioning does a pretty good job of not messing you your system. You could give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks, But I need Ubuntu on my system. Why partition like this show?